# Cassandra installation on Windows 7

Tags: windows, cassandra

I have done the following on Windows 7 for running Cassandra:

Installed Python.

Downloaded a zip of Cassandra from the original site.

While executing cassandra batch getting following messages:

```
Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "The system cannot find the file
specified" At E:\apache-cassandra-3.11.2\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:212 char:5


+     $p.Start() | Out-Null
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Win32Exception
```

Comment: There is very limited support for running Cassandra on Windows. I would recommend running it in a VM if you just want to test things out. Datastax used to provide a Datastax Community edition (basically their own packaging of Cassandra) but unfortunately they stopped after 3.9.0. With that knowledge you could still try it out as it's probably the fastest way to get started: https://academy.datastax.com/planet-cassandra/cassandra

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out https://kimola.com/cassandrows. I am in the same situation of wanting to install Cassandra on Windows. But I do not want to be left behind with version 3.9.0.